# Need "iOS like app" organization for web app

Tags: javascript, ipad, layout, web, portlet

I'm researching WebUI toolkits to make a web based financial app that does not need to be mobile friendly...users will be on desktop/laptop. However the users would like to view the different financial tools as "apps", similar to how app icons are organized and displayed on an iOS device.  Best I can describe it is imagine your iPad screen with all the app icons in row column order...basically a web page implementation of that except the differed apps would be (launch) web based financial tools.

Any ideas on stuff to look at? Any experiences doing something similar? I looked around and found zilch along these lines.

Comment: http://chocolatechip-ui.com

Comment: Not a bad toolkit but not what I'm primarily looking for.  Looking more for a tool to organize app'like icons similar to the face of an iphone/ipad.  I'm being lazy and hoping there's something I can use because project timeline is tight.  On a path to use bootstrap and jquery magic unless we find something better.

Comment: Well, try not being lazy.